# Symfony and Doctrine Metadata Cache

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, apc

I am trying to optimize my Symfony application performances and I followed these posts:

- https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/performance.html
- [Symfony2 Slow Initialization Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905404/symfony2-slow-initialization-time/17914570#17914570)

I am "worried" about these lines:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                metadata_cache_driver: apc
                query_cache_driver: apc
                result_cache_driver: apc
```

Are they **safe** to use or I must handle them with care after deploy?
I am clearing the cache with `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`, do I need to clear APC cache too?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, in general, you should clear your APC cache after deployment. But it depends on what you've changed since your last deployment.

`cache:clear` won't clear the Doctrine cache. It only clears your cache directory (`var/cache/{env}` for Symfony 3+, `app/cache` for 2.8): [FrameworkBundle/Command/CacheClearCommand.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/CacheClearCommand.php)

So you should clear the cache after deployment if something (for example your entities) has changed since the last deployment.

If you deploy manually, run these commands if applicable:

```
bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-query --env=prod
bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-result --env=prod
bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata --env=prod
```

If you prefer *better safe than sorry* or if you deployment automatically, run all of them.

Unfortunately, the APC cache can't be clear using CLI. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42534999/1405981) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40041362/apc-clear-cache-not-working-from-command-line-in-php). As an alternative, you can [restart your webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6682101/1405981).

Comment: I am using Symfony 2.8 and the cache directory is inside app, is it the same thing? I am using deployer for deploying my Symfony app but it doesn't seem to haandle Doctrine cache: https://github.com/deployphp/deployer/blob/master/recipe/symfony.php

Comment: Updated my answer. 'app/cache' was used before Symfony 3.0. I see deployer does not clear your Doctrine cache. See [this issue](https://github.com/deployphp/deployer/issues/444) for some background information.

Comment: Thanks! Last two questions: 1) do I need to specify the `--flush` parameter? 2) There is a comment in the post you linked: "If you use apc, you can't delete the cache using command", what does it mean?

Comment: I add another comment. In production I received this error: `Cannot clear APC Cache from Console, its shared in the Webserver memory and not accessible from the CLI.`
I noticed that in my deploy recipe I am already restarting PHP-FPM with `sudo /etc/init.d/php7.0-fpm restart`, is it already clearing APC cache?

Comment: You should execute `apc_clear_cache()`. See my updated answer.

Comment: What about FPM? If restarting FPM will suffice would you please add it to the solution so I can accept it? Thanks.

Comment: I added a link to an answer about restarting your webserver!

Comment: Where is this cache stored which is cleared by `doctrine:cache:clear-*` commands?